# How to troubleshoot app not working for one user?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a user that has the identical phone to mine, Samsung Galaxy 5S.  I download my app and install it to my phone just fine, app works as its supposed to.  When my user downloads it, it appears to install correctly but when she opens the app she sees the splash screen and then the screen goes blank.

Identical phones, same version of the app...but because the app is compiled already I can't troubleshoot the app on her phone via Chrome Inspector.

How else can I troubleshoot what is going on here...I am worried its my app causing this but since its installing on my phone and others just fine I am hoping its just something specific to her phone.

Comment: You could use a crash-reporting service such as Firebase or Flurry; at least you will get a stacktrace to look at.

Comment: Yes, in these kinds of cases, you need some form of telemetry. It's a very common problem in mobile apps. You could either log various exceptions into a database or log file, or use an external service as per the suggestion above.